# Class Destructor call when using multithreading on socketcan

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, destructor, socketcan

I am trying to understand why the class destructor is being called right at the beginning after the program starts !?

Here is my program snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/can.h>
#include <linux/can/raw.h>

class Canloop {
private:
    int socketFileDescriptor;
    struct sockaddr_can socketAdressConfig;
    struct ifreq interfaceRequestConfig;
    struct can_frame canFrameRx;
    struct can_frame canFrameTx;
    int sendCounter{0};
    std::thread receive_;
    std::thread transmit_;
    std::mutex readWriteMutex;
    std::atomic<bool> running{true};

    void receiveThread();
    void transmitThread();

public:
    Canloop(std::string &canInterface);
    void setCanData(can_frame &);
    void start();
    void stop();
    ~Canloop();
};

Canloop::Canloop(std::string &canInterface) {
    if ((socketFileDescriptor = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW)) < 0) {
        perror("Socket");
    }

    strcpy(interfaceRequestConfig.ifr_name, canInterface.c_str());
    ioctl(socketFileDescriptor, SIOCGIFINDEX, &interfaceRequestConfig);

    memset(&socketAdressConfig, 0, sizeof(socketAdressConfig));
    socketAdressConfig.can_family = AF_CAN;
    socketAdressConfig.can_ifindex = interfaceRequestConfig.ifr_ifindex;

    if (bind(socketFileDescriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&socketAdressConfig, sizeof(socketAdressConfig)) < 0) {
        perror("Bind");
    }

    int flags = fcntl(socketFileDescriptor, F_GETFL, 0);
    if (flags == -1) {
        perror("fcntl non blocking set error");
    }

    flags != O_NONBLOCK;
    if (fcntl(socketFileDescriptor, F_SETFL, flags) == -1) {
        perror("fcntl");
    }

    int bufferSize = 2;
    if (setsockopt(socketFileDescriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &bufferSize, sizeof(bufferSize))) {
        perror("setsocketopt");
    }
    if (setsockopt(socketFileDescriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &bufferSize, sizeof(bufferSize))) {
        perror("setsocketopt");
    }

    struct timeval timeout;

    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = 1000;

    if (setsockopt(socketFileDescriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout))) {
        perror("time set error");
    }

    if (setsockopt(socketFileDescriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout))) {
        perror("time set error");
    }
}

void Canloop::start() {
    receive_ = std::thread([=] { receiveThread(); });
    transmit_ = std::thread([=] { transmitThread(); });
}

void Canloop::setCanData(can_frame &data) {
    this->canFrameTx = data;
}

void Canloop::stop() {
    if (close(socketFileDescriptor) < 0) {
        perror("Close");
    }

    running = false;
    if (receive_.joinable()) {
        receive_.join();
    }

    if (transmit_.joinable()) {
        transmit_.join();
    }
}

void Canloop::receiveThread() {
    std::cout << "Starting Rx_ " << std::endl;

    while (running) {
        ssize_t bytesRead;
        {
            // Mutex to guard the socket for Read access
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(readWriteMutex);
            bytesRead = read(socketFileDescriptor, &canFrameRx, sizeof(struct can_frame));
        }
        if (running) {
            if (bytesRead == -1) {
                if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
                    // Handle non-blocking read
                } else {
                    perror("read error");
                }
            } else if (bytesRead == sizeof(struct can_frame)) {
                // Print data
                printf("0x%03X [%d] ", canFrameRx.can_id, canFrameRx.can_dlc);
                for (int i = 0; i < canFrameRx.can_dlc; i++)
                    printf("%02X ", canFrameRx.data[i]);
                printf("\r\n");
            } else {
                std::cout << "Incomplete data" << std::endl;
            }
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }
    }
}

void Canloop::transmitThread() {
    std::cout << "Starting Tx_" << std::endl;

    while (running) {
        ssize_t nbytes ;
        {
            // Lock for write
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(readWriteMutex);
            nbytes = write(socketFileDescriptor, &canFrameTx, sizeof(struct can_frame));
        }
            if (running && nbytes == -1) {
                if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
                    std::cout << "Would block" << std::endl;
                } else if (errno == ENOBUFS) {
                    perror("Buffer fail: ");
                } else {
                    perror("Write fail");
                }
            }
        
        std::cout << "Data written " << sendCounter++ << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}

Canloop::~Canloop() {

    std::cout << "Destructor called" << std::endl;
    if (transmit_.joinable()) {
            transmit_.join();
    }

    if(receive_.joinable()) {
        receive_.join();
    }

    
}

int main() {
    std::string canInterface("can0");
    Canloop cantester(canInterface);

    can_frame localCanData;
    char hello[5] = "Hell";
    localCanData.can_id = 0x123;
    localCanData.can_dlc = sizeof(hello) / sizeof(hello[0]);
    sprintf((char *)localCanData.data, hello);
    cantester.setCanData(localCanData);
    cantester.start();
    return 0;
}
```

As i never shutdown the program, neither destroy the class explicitly, the destructor should not be invoked. Yet i see the following output.

```
Starting Rx_
Starting Tx_
Destructor called
Data written 0
Data written 1
Data written 2
Data written 3
Data written 4
Data written 5
Data written 6
Data written 7
Data written 8
Data written 9
```

Why is it being called ? I do not expect an invoke !?

Comment: Try deleting the copy and move constructors, to rule out having TWO instances, of which one gets destroyed early.

Comment: Also, `cantester` is a variable with automatic storage duration, so its destructor will run automatically when you return from its scope.

Comment: What do you mean by "I never shutdown the program" and why do you think `return 0;` in `main()` doesn't count?

Comment: @BenVoigt  Does the context switch during multithreading count towards the variable going out of scope ? yes , but the scope of the variable is main, so till it remains in main it should not be destroyed ?

Comment: The whole point of threads is that they all make progress independently.  So `main()` continues until it hits `return 0;`, leaves the scope, calls the destructors for local variables.  The only thing that keeps your program from exiting is that `join()` inside the destructor.

Comment: @rebelliousconformist *Yet i see the following output.* -- You should use the debugger and set a breakpoint inside the destructor.  Then once you do that, look at the call stack when the breakpoint is hit.  That is far better than printing output statements if you want to see where the call of the destructor is coming from.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 
 https://imgur.com/a/mR44xCL . as Ben pointed out the main is executed and the control moves to the destructor from main.